# Simpler way to render list of objects as JSON in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, list

I want to render a list of objects into JSON, but I don't want to user to_json because I want to render a very specific format and subset of information.

This is my view (`foo.json.erb`):

```
{
"id" : <%= @user.id %>,
"progress" : [
    <% @rewards_tapped[0..-2].each do |reward| %>
        <%= render "rewardprogress", :reward => reward, 
                                     :user => @user %>,
    <% end %>
    <%= render "rewardprogress", :reward => @rewards_tapped.last, 
                                 :user => @user %>
]
}
```

As you can see, it is pretty ugly because I have to render the last item in @rewards_tapped separately so that it does not have a comma after the entry (to make valid JSON).

There has to be a better way to do this, I'm just a bit new to Ruby.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require incremental rendering, then you could simply build up a nested hash/array Ruby data structure, and call `#to_json` on that. You can also use symbols as keys, and they'll become string keys in the resulting JSON.

Assuming you do need the incremental rendering, then this might be a minor improvement you could make (or might just be replacing one kind of ugly with another).  This might be faster though if converting `@rewards_tapped` to an array for `[0..-2]` is at all slow.

```
{
"id" : <%= @user.id %>,
"progress" : [
    <% @rewards_tapped.each_with_index do |reward, idx|
    %><%= idx == 0 ? '' : ',' %>
    <%= render "rewardprogress", :reward => reward, 
                                     :user => @user
    %><% end %>
]
}
```

Comment: This is cleaner, to some extent.  At least it's DRY.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try a different templating system like [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) or [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

Comment: Umm.. why is a parser required here?

Comment: It's not a parser, it's a templating system.